# Core telephony CTCarrier and isoCountryCode. How to get user's current cellular provider's country?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to get user's current country without asking for location. So I thought using  `CTCarrier` class property `isoCountryCode`. To get access to `CTCarrier` I'm using `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders`, which returns *"A dictionary that contains carrier information about each service"*.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/3024511-servicesubscribercellularprovide.

Now when I query `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` it returns 2 objects - `nil` and presumably my home cellular service provider.

```
          let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
          let dictionary = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders;
          for (type, value) in dictionary ?? [:] {
              let country:String? = value.isoCountryCode == nil ? "nil" : value.isoCountryCode;
              print("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders: "+country!)
          }
```

If I was abroad and connected to roaming service provider would I still get two objects - home and now instead of `nil` - roaming service provider? And inside roaming service provider property `isoCountryCode` would return the actual country of the roaming service provider?

The documentation is confusing for me... What exactly is `isoCountryCode` for home cellular service provider? Let's say I live in France and my service provider is of course from France - `isoCountryCode` would return *"FR"*. Now if I go on a vacation to Germany - what `isoCountryCode` would return now? Still the same *"FR"* or *"DE"*?

Comment: No. iPhones can have two sims; one physical sim and one esim

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh I see, so that's nothing to do with home/roaming service providers?

Comment: @Paulw11 , just add that in some country like HongKong, iPhone have 2 physical sims : it is a requirement.

Comment: `isoCountryCode` is marked as deprecated in **iOS 16** and will give '--' in the future, did you find any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation explains:

> **Note**
>
> In this context, the “home” provider is the one with which the user has a cellular plan, as opposed to a roaming provider.

So, you will always get FR, even when roaming, if your home provider is in France.

The reason there are two possible values is that iPhones now support up to two sims; One physical and one e-SIM, so there may be two different cellular providers on a phone.

Comment: Urgh well that sucks :).. Is there a way to get a roaming service provider?

Comment: If you want the users location it's best to be up front and ask for it. You can ask for approximate location.

Comment: Sure, but in our case we need to consider those, who will deny access to location... That's why we're investigating other ways... For example in seems to be working on Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getNetworkCountryIso(). Thanks!

Comment: While Android is improving privacy protections they are not as strong as Apple's. If Apple thought it was a good idea to expose location data via cellular information they would do so. Even if they did, I am certain they would require you to get the user's permission before such data was made available to you.  You should explain your need for location to the user and if they decline to provide it then you can either accept that or your app can not function.

Comment: I agree with you 100%! So be it - no location,no party :)! Thanks!